# How can I inherit a class which inherits db.Model

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I try to create another sql table using sqlalchemy by combining with a flask application

I have a class `Table1` `db.model` which has some functionality and I want to use it's functionality by creating another `Table2` class-table with some extra columns (which inherits the existing one), unfortunately when I tried to do this the automated form mechanism of SQLAlchemy did not create the `table` as it did with other classes which inherits `db.model`

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Table1(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "table1"

   id                   = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)

class Table2(Table1):
   __tablename__ = "table2"

   id                   = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)
   extra_column         = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes but I am inheriting `db.Model` and not `declarative_base`

Comment: Just a guess, but do you need to `super()` `Table1` in `__init__` for `Table2` ?

Comment: @match 
`class Table2(Table1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.super()
        self.__tablename__ = "table2"` I did this but it does not work

Comment: `db.Model` is a declarative base class, albeit a customized one. You seem to be trying to set up joined inheritance, but the child model has no foreign key reference to the parent. `Table2.id` looks like it should be that reference, but having `extra_column` form a composite primary key with `id` messes that up. Thinking about it, it's not logical. Only one row of the child table should reference a parent row, or else 2 instances of `Table2` would share state (stored in table1).

Comment: And one other common reason for tables not being created is that the model does not yet exist when `db.create_all()` or such is called. In other words it has not been imported/the module containing it evaluated, so it does not exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `__abstract__ = True` to Table1 BUT Table1 will not be created by SQLAlchemy ORM system

```
      db = SQLAlchemy(app)



      class Table1(db.Model):
           __tablename__ = "table1"
           __abstract__ = True

           id                   = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)

        class Table2(Table1):
           __tablename__ = "table2"

           id                   = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)
           extra_column         = db.Column(db.String(36),  primary_key=True)
```